# Count number of occurrences of first column value respectively across each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
data = [['BAL', 'BAL', 'NO', 'DAL'], ['DAL', 'DAL', 'TEN', 'SF']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of the value in the first column in each row, across that row.

In this example, the number of times "BAL" appears in the first row, "DAL" in the second row, etc.

Then assign that count to a new column `df['Count']`.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Comment: @HenryEcker: ok. Why then wasn't the title simply "Count number of occurrences of first column value respectively across a row?"... the title was more vague and mismatched the question body. It made it sound like the target-values could come from some arbitrary column-vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
df.assign(count=df.eq(df.iloc[:,0], axis=0).sum(axis=1))
```

Create a series using `iloc` of the first column of your dataframe, then compare values use pd.DataFrame.eq with axis=0 and `sum` along axis=1.

Output:

```
     0    1    2    3  count
0  BAL  BAL   NO  DAL      2
1  DAL  DAL  TEN   SF      2
```

Answer (score 3):

We can compare the first column to all the remaining columns with [`DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) across the rows to add up the number of `True` values (matches):

```
df['count'] = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq(df.iloc[:, 0], axis=0).sum(axis=1)
```

`df`:

```
     0    1    2    3  count
0  BAL  BAL   NO  DAL      1
1  DAL  DAL  TEN   SF      1
```

*Note this output is slightly different than the accepted answer in that it does not include the column containing the reference values in the row count.

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why would the count of the first row be zero? I can see how it would be 1 (i.e. `BAL` appears once excluding the first column) or 2 (`BAL` appears twice in the row).

Comment: Thank you. I missed a step in my copying @Robson fixed.